# how can I add javascript or Jquery to my navbar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to add js to my navbar, I want to make it like if I click another button, the class of that button become 'active', and the others become normal one

```
<ul>
<li><a class="nav-link active" href="">Home</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-link" href="">Semester</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-link" href="">Course</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-link" href="">Class</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-link" href="">Lecturer</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-link" href="">Student</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-link" href="">Student Attendance</a></li>
```

Comment: Share us what you've tried until now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav-link").click(function () {
        $(".nav-link").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

do this and move the .nav-link class to li tag

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav-link").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

This an effective way to create visual and operational navigation bars on web pages. The code adds the active class to li that was clicked and remove from every other li within its parent ul